# Thunderbird on Windows: missing folders with non-Latin names after restoring from a backup

Tags: windows, backup, thunderbird, locale, non-ascii

I've copied my Thunderbird profile (a directory called like `f4gokpr4.default`) from one Windows 10 machine to another Windows 10 machine. Account names are the same, all absolute paths I know about are the same as well.

However, now a lot of folders in my POP account are missing in the interface. Top-level folders are there, but they contain no letters and no subfolders.

The thing in common is these directories have Cyrillic/non-Latin names like `Работа` and contain special characters like `Путешествия/Отдых` (that's a single folder, not a subfolder). In the profile folder they correspond to files/directories `Работа`/`Работа.msf`/`Работа.sbd`, and something like `Путешествияf88e4aec`/`Путешествияf88e4aec.msf`/`Путешествияf88e4aec.sbd`. Cyrillic characters are stored as-is, and everything after a special character is truncated.

However, on the new system Thunderbird thinks that these folders should be stored in a newly created directories like `44d8f9af`/`44d8f9af.msf`/`44d8f9af.sbd`. These directories are created in the profile, are empty, and no files/directories are moved from the previous location.

All-Latin directories work fine.

How do I make Thunderbird use the old directories instead of trying to give them new names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a kludgy solution on [Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1269793): turns out my profile was created on a machine which has used `Russian (Russia)` as the system locale (`Current language for non-Unicode programs`), but the new machine has `English (United States)` instead.

Solution: switch the new machine to use `Russian (Russia)` locale as well, restore from backup one more time.

As far as I understand, this affects the default non-Unicode encoding, and Cyrillic characters can be encoded using `Russian (Russia)`, but not `English (United States)`. It seems that Thunderbird either uses non-Unicode API to query the filesystem, or uses this system setting to determine how to store directories on the disk.

Comment: +1. Very interesting. I wonder, after the backup, can you now switch locale to english? or are you now stuck on russian? And also, if you can switch to english, would a backup then allow being imported on a system that was never russian?

Comment: @LPChip I'm stuck with the Russian locale. If I switch to English, folders disappear. If I then switch back to Russian, folders reappear, but their duplicates with ASCII-only directory names remain, so I end up with 2-3 copies of each folder in Thunderbird.

Comment: Odd. Too bad that happens. You can try unzipping the export and see if you can edit anything and import it back as english.